# as3 replaceAll insensitive

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have this as3 function

```
public static function StringReplaceAll( source:String, find:String, replacement:String ) : String {
      return source.split( find ).join( replacement );
}
```

Works fine: any idea how to make it case insenstive ?
Regards

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use the [String#replace()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace%28%29) function.

for example:

```
trace("HELLO there".replace(/e/gi, "a"));
//traces HaLLO thara
```

The first argument in the replace function is a regular expression. You'll find information about them [all over the web](http://www.google.be/search?q=regular%20esxpression). And there's this handy tool from Grant Skinner called [Regexr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) with which you can test your regular expressions ActionScript style.

The part between the two forward slashes (/) is the actual regex.

- The '**g**' after the regex means "replace globally" (i.e. all occurrences of the letter 'e' in the example, without the 'g' it would just replace the first occurrence).
- The '**i**' means "do a case insensitive search" (in the example, without the 'i' the capital E wouldn't have been replaced).

Note that `/e/gi` is actually just a shorthand for `new RegExp("e", "gi")`

Comment: +1 also note that split function can also take a RegEx for the first parameter, but the replace function is obviously the way to go

Answer (score -1):

A quick way could be to do two replacements. One for the lowerCase and one for the upperCase. It'll look something like this:

```
public static function StringReplaceAll( source:String, find:String, replacement:String ) : String 
{

    var replacedLowerCase:String = StringReplace(source, find.toLowerCase(), replacement.toLowerCase());

    return StringReplace(replacedLowerCase, find.toUpperCase(), replacement.toUpperCase());
}

private static function StringReplace( source:String, find:String, replacement:String ) : String 
{
    return source.split(find).join(replacement);
}
```

So in this case you'll keep the case of your `find` intact i.e.:

```
trace(StringReplaceAll('HELLO there', 'e', 'a'));
// traces HALLO thara
```

If you don't want to keep the case intact @RIAstar's `String.replace()` answer is cleaner.
(But you could of course also use his example twice for that matter)

Comment: how does it not work? `trace(StringReplaceAll("HEeLLO theere", "e", "a"));` puts out `HAaLLO thaara` just fine